# Windows Explorer won't open outside of Task Manager

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I have absolutely no idea why, but Windows Explorer won't open in most cases.  If I double-click on a folder on my desktop, click a link on the Start Menu, or click the Windows Explorer icon on my task bar, a spinny cursor will appear for around 2 seconds and then will disappear.  Nothing will happen.

The only way I managed to get Explorer to open is by running `explorer.exe "C:\"` in Windows Task Manager.  This is very inefficient as I need to navigate to the desired folder after opening Task Manager.

Comment: try running `sfc.exe /scannow` to determine if there is a problem with your sytsem files. Uninstall any applications that add functionality to explorer like Context Menus or custom items in My Computer. Scour the event log for error messages.

Comment: I ran the SFC scan and it found nothing.  All I have is AVG PC TuneUp and that has been installed for quite a while before this issue appeared.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Run an antivirus too. Things that you double-click on may not be what they seem. Check the folder/file properties carefully.

Comment: Derp!  I was holding off on restarting because I had a project to finish but restarting did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

All I needed to do was restart. This seems to have fixed the problem